# stop closing the modal by clicking backdrop or outside the modal

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have used one angular2 [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) modal in our code.

I want the modal will not close when I click outside the modal. Currently, the modal is getting closed while clicking outside.

In Angular1 I used to do this by:

```
[keyboard]="false"
[backdrop]="'static'"
```

But this time it is not working in Angular2.

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RhXR0QZ2DiOJoK58MpjB)

My Open method is as follows:

```
  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

As per the answer of @anshuVersatile, I understand we need to use some modal options.

Then I create a object of [NgbModalOptions](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) and pass it as second parameter of my open method and it works.

Code is as follows :

```
let ngbModalOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
      backdrop : 'static',
      keyboard : false
};
console.log(ngbModalOptions);
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent, ngbModalOptions);
```

Here is the updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hRzOXTaqRkAw43HnUym1?p=preview).

Comment: Note that there's a similar, but completely independent angular bootstrap library 'ngx-bootstrap'. The options you need to set are different for this - see https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-disable-backdrop. You'll need  `let config = {
      backdrop: true,
      ignoreBackdropClick: true
    };`
then ...
`this.modalService.show(SomeComponent, config);`

Comment: loading... in plunker => Error {originalErr: Error, constructor: Object}

Answer (score 17):

```
$modal.open({
   // ... other options
   backdrop  : 'static',
   keyboard  : false
});
```

While you creating your modal you can specify its behavior:

Comment: Is it Angular2 code? I don't think so. I am expecting Angular2 code.

Comment: Yes, this _is_ Angular code (in fact it is just JavaScript as options to ng-bootstrap modal service are just an object literal). As the author of this component I can also say that it is a correct answer and should be accepted. Good job @anshuVersatile

Comment: I am using TypeScript and Angular2 here, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 12):

Though it is late still  it might be helpful for somebody else facing the issue:

```
 const config: ModalOptions = {
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false,
                animated: true,
                ignoreBackdropClick: true,
                initialState: {
                  data1: 'new-user',
                  username: 'test'
                }
              };
              this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(MyComponent, config);
```

initialState object is used to pass data to modal.

Comment: Working with ngx-bootstrap with angular 9

Answer (score 5):

In case of ngx-bootstrap/modal in angular 2+ (bsmodal) use [config]="{ backdrop: 'static' }", 
.ts file like

```
import {ModalDirective} from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
@ViewChild('myModal') public myModal: ModalDirective;

 openpopup(){
     this.myModal.show()
  }
```

and .html like

```
<button class="btn btn-md btn-pill btn-success mb-3 pull-right" type="button" data-toggle="modal" (click)="openpopup()">Open</button>

 <div bsModal #myModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade"  [config]="{ backdrop: 'static' }"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Popup heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" (click)="myModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <!---- popup content here---->
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: I take it as answer. [config]="{ backdrop: 'static' }"

Answer (score 3):

**In your component.ts file**

```
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

//--------

constructor(
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) {}

@ViewChild('sampleModal', {static: true}) sampleModalRef: TemplateRef<any>;

modalRef: BsModalRef;

config = {
    backdrop: true,
    ignoreBackdropClick: true
  };

//-------

open() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.sampleModalRef, this.config);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<ng-template #sampleModal>
      .
      .
      .
      .
</ng-template>
```