# NgbModal closes when i click outside despide defining backdrop to static

Tags: angular

Im using NgbModal to open a template the following way:

```
this.modalReference = this.modalService.open(template, MODAL_OPTIONS);
```

`MODAL_OPTIONS` is defined the following way:

```
export const MODAL_OPTIONS: NgbModalOptions = {backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false};
```

The documentation states that the `MODAL_OPTIONS`definition above is supposed to prevent the modal to be closed when i click outside of it. Thats also what was recommended in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438160/stop-closing-the-modal-by-clicking-backdrop-or-outside-the-modal). But it doesnt work for me. The modal still closes when i click outside. Does anyone know what causes that behaviour?

Comment: can you share your modal html

Answer (score 0):

### Try removing export

```
let ngbModalOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
  backdrop : 'static',
  keyboard : false
};

const modalRef = this.modalService.open(template, MODAL_OPTIONS);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/modal-config.ts

Have look at this example from docs.

You can inject an instance of `NgbModalConfig` in your component and then change that as per your component's requirement.

> ```
> // customize default values of modals used by this component tree
> config.backdrop = 'static';
> config.keyboard = false;
> ```

Full example for reference

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModalConfig, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-config',
  templateUrl: './modal-config.html',
  // add NgbModalConfig and NgbModal to the component providers
  providers: [NgbModalConfig, NgbModal]
})
export class NgbdModalConfig {
  constructor(config: NgbModalConfig, private modalService: NgbModal) {
    // customize default values of modals used by this component tree
    config.backdrop = 'static';
    config.keyboard = false;
  }

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content);
  }
}
```